# How to pass variable from one parameterized method to another?

Tags: java

How do I send the variable from main method to the Method `A`, and what Parameter should I pass within `A()`, in method `B`.

**Code:**

```java
public class MethodCall {
    
    public void A(String c) {
        
        System.out.println(c);
    }
    
    public void B() {
        A(); // What parameter do I pass here. method B is dependent on A
        
    }
    @Test
    public void D() {
        B();
        MethodCall mc = new MethodCall();
        mc.A("Hello");
    }

}
```

Comment: what param you need in method `A()` ?

Comment: My issue is in mehod B(), I donot want to pass any parameter for A(), but i cant keep it blank, it will throw error.

Comment: then please put `""` empty string  or `null` whichever you think is best, FYI is not a good practice

Comment: @PalashChatterjee your example is too abstract to give you an answer that makes sense for a general case.

Comment: I know it is not a good practise, still what would you suggest as a good parctise.

Comment: By the way if method `A` needs to be called from `B` then `B` simply needs to be provided all the things it needs to call `A`. That means either passing something as a parameter to `B` itself or letting `B` take that parameter from... somewhere. That "somewhere" depends on specific cases.

Answer (score 0):

In method `A` you expect one parameter of type `String` therefore you have to provide a parameter for `String` can be just an empty String `""` or `null`.

---

Another option depending on your use case; you could use varargs:

```java
public void a(String... varargs) {...}
```

In this case it's possible to give zero or multiple parameters of type `String`.
So this works:

```java
a("Hello World");
```

this:

```java
a();
```

But also this:

```java
a("Hello", "World");
```

---

Or you could just pass all parameters necessary for `A` through `B`:

```java
public class MethodCall {
    public void A(String c) {
        System.out.println(c);
    }
    
    public void B(String c) {
        A(c);
    }
    @Test
    public void D() {
        MethodCall mc = new MethodCall();
        mc.B("Hello World");
        mc.A("Hello");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the String parameter for within A(), in method B.

```
public class MethodCall {

    public void A(String c) {
    
        System.out.println(c);
    }

    public void B() {
        A("Pass the String parameter"); 
    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MethodCall mc = new MethodCall();
        mc.A("Hello");
        mc.B();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

when you passing the String type as a parameter its mean you should use to same data type when you giving the value to the parameter. you cant use any other types like Integer, float etc. you just need to pass the String value to the given parameter.

> When you are using non-static method it cannot call directly. so use
> static keyword to call the method in directly.

***ANSWER-***

```
public class MethodCall {
    
    public static void A(String c) {
        
        System.out.println(c);
    }
    
    public static void B() {
        A("HI "); //you can put `null` or `empty`
        
    }

    public static  void main(String[] args) {
        B();
        MethodCall mc = new MethodCall();
        mc.A("Hello");
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

I am not so sure about your question but here is my take:

```
    public class MethodCall {

    public void A(String c) {

    System.out.println(c);
    }

    public void B(String s) {
    A(s); //If you want to call A() here, then you would have to pass a variable in the parameters of A(), as A() is a parameterized method by definition.

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MethodCall mc = new MethodCall();
    mc.A("Hello"); //This part is right, that is how you pass value of a non static function through main method.
    }
```